# Unity3D: Why is particle lighting making directional shadows disappear?

Tags: unity-game-engine

**UPDATE:** As @BenHayward suspected, this is a bug. <[link](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/light-module-particle-lights-interfere-with-directional-light-shadows)>

I have a very simple setup of cubes on a plane comprising a grid of quads. A directional light is shining down at the scene at an angle, producing a set of shadows from the cubes onto the quads.

Now I'm trying to produce an explosion effect with Unity's particle system, but when I add a point light to the particle system it causes all the directional-lighting shadows to disappear, whether they're in line of sight of the particle or not.

The shadows reappear when the particle is destroyed. Replicating the particle effect with pure C# doesn't cause any problems.

(Oh, and obviously I'm using the deferred rendering path.)

Any ideas? This is driving me off the wall.

[EDIT: I should have mentioned that the point light added to the particle system is set to cast shadows. The Unity standard particle pack has shadow-casting disabled by default. They too cause the problem when I turn the shadow-casting on.]

Comment: Can you add what version of unity you are using?

Comment: It's 5.6.0f3 Personal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the project that you linked to, it seems as though the particle system is causing the shadow cast from the directional light to flicker on and off quickly. I suspect this is a bug, since if it were intended behaviour, I wouldn't expect it to flicker in this manner.

In cases where this is not a bug, the problem can be caused by a couple of issues:

1. You can only have a certain number of dynamic (shadow casting) lights in your scene which are seen by the camera frustum. By default, this number is quite low (I think it's 4). You can increase this number by going to Edit > Project Settings > Quality. Set the Pixel Light count higher from its default value. You will need to increase this value to be greater than the total number of lights in your effect. Higher values will allow more lights to be rendered on the screen, but this reduces performance.

[image: Screenshot of where to find Pixel Light count in Unity interface]

2. It depends on the shaders which you are using to receive the shadows. Some shaders will only render shadows for one directional light. The light which is used isn't necessarily too easy to determine. If you are using the standard Unity shader this shouldn't be a problem. But if you are using a mobile compatible surface shader or something you've written yourself then this could be the cause of the problem.

Also, for an explosion, I'd recommend using just one single point light (not lights attached to each particle), as this is all that is required. Any more lights would result in considerable performance impact on the GPU especially if there are more than one explosion in the scene at any one time.

Comment: I thought it might be the pixel light count, but no truck. The problem persists even with a pixel light count that is frankly ridiculous (I've tried everything from 20–100). The test scene uses Unity's prefabs from Unity's standard asset pack, which utilise the default shaders. Also, I'm only generating a single light per effect, not per particle. Hmmm =(

Comment: If you're able to upload the project, I'd take a look for you

Comment: Thanks, Ben! I'll put something together quickly.

Comment: Here is a link to a bare-bones project showing the issue: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/31715218985235200b64cbfc752c9fe020170623121213/214d5a2b64c4ddecb39b5c25cd45aedf20170623121213/87c8a4

Comment: Hi @crisis.sheep I can see that the shadow from the directional light is flickering on and off when the particle light is showing. is this the behaviour you are describing? btw, I opened the project in 2017.1.0.b5

Comment: Hiya @Ben, yes, that's what I'm describing. It's much worse in my actual project – the directional shadows simply disappear across the entire level for the duration of the particle light's existence.

Comment: I can only think this is a bug - I don't believe it would flicker in the same way if it was intended behaviour. As a workaround, are you able to just use a single light source (without using a particle system to facilitate it) which you control with a keyframed animation? I presume the reason you chose to use a particle system was so that you could easily configure the lighting effect and see immediate results?

Comment: Blast it all, I feared it might be a bug. Okay, I'll try the workaround you suggested and see how that goes.

Comment: You can submit a bug report to Unity - they're usually very good at responding and trying to fix it in my experience :)

Comment: The keyframing works perfectly! Nice! I'll definitely submit a bug report. I can't mark your main answer as correct, alas, but this defs deserves the bounty. Thanks very much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147462/discussion-between-crisis-sheep-and-ben-hayward).

Comment: Nice, let's hope they patch it quickly :)

Answer (score -1):

I recreated the scene as you described, i can't recreate your issue.
i mostly followed this tutorial, and added a few cubes in a plane:

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/graphics/adding-lighting-particles

I will need a screenshot of your lights componnents, both the directional and the point light, the particles, and the cubes (mostly the material); I cannot comment because i dont have enough reputation yet, so i'll delete this once you add the screenshots;

Comment: Is the lighting you've attached to your particle effect set to cast shadows? Because even the standard particle pack from Unity causes my problem when I turn shadow-casting on.